# Using recursion repeated value getting in string list in java

Tags: java, recursion

I want list of names from table based on record selection.

For example If I select Id = 1 then I need list value (A,b,c,d) with all their child of child.

Following is my table data.

Id(1,2,3,4,5) name(a,b,c,d,e) ParentId(-,1,1,3,-)

Following is my code for recursion

```
public List<String> selectData(int orgId) {
    String parentId = String.valueOf(orgId);        

    List<Object> listData = selectAllData();// here parent select
    List<String> returnList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Object parents : listData) {


            List<String> list = this.getChildFor(parents.getId());

            for (String child : list) {
                returnList.add(child);
            }

    }
    for(String enty : listData){
        returnList.add(enty);
    }
    return returnList;
}

public List<String> getChildFor(int orgId) {

    String parentId = String.valueOf(orgId);
    int pId = 0;
    List<Object> listData = selectByExample(); // here child select from all record based on orgId.
    List<String> returnList = new ArrayList<String>();
    do {
        for (Object parents : listData) {
                returnList.add(parents.name);
                List<String> list = this.getChildFor(parents.getId);
                for (String child : list) {
                    returnList.add(child.getname());
                }

        }
        pId = 0;
    } while (pId != 0);
    for(String enty : listData){
        returnList.add(enty);
    }
    listData = null;
    return returnList;
}
```

In "returnList" list I got duplicate value.
Anyone give me idea on this thanks.

Comment: What makes you believe you shouldn't be getting a duplicate value?

Comment: When I select Id 1 I got value something like (a,b,a,b,c,d). I need value with all their child of child like for id 1 I need (a,b,c,d).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `getChildFor` method you iterate `listData` twice.

Try to remove the

```
for(String enty : listData){
    returnList.add(enty);
}
```

because it's already added in the `returnList.add(parents.name);`